# How to travel long distance in India during "Janatha Curfew"?

Tags: india, covid-19, curfews

Recently due to COVID-19 outbreak, India prime minister Narendra Modi declared "[Janatha Curfew](https://www.ndtv.com/india-news/pm-modi-on-coronavirus-pandemic-the-world-is-passing-through-a-huge-crisis-more-countries-affected-t-2197582)" on March 22 2020 (sunday). Even Indian Railways won't run. How to travel long distance in India during "Janatha Curfew"?

Comment: Surely the whole point of the curfew is to limit travel and social interaction in an effort to contain the virus. If you can't travel, don't. It's only one day. Travel on Monday.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking how to break the law.

Comment: It's a one-day curfew test, so just travel on Saturday or Monday instead?

Comment: @Willeke that is not.necessarily true.  The law presumably has exceptions, as do all of the travel restrictions I've seen so far.  The linked article quottes an exception for "essential services."  Suppose someone whose work is an essential service needs to travel a long distance to return to work or as part of providing the service

Comment: @Xiang Yin Is your long distance travel 100% essential? If not, don’t travel.

Comment: Re-opened on request.

Comment: `"Even Indian Railways won't run"` - Do you have a source for this quote? The best I can find is Delhi metro won't be running during that time. Many Indian long distance trains take more than a day to complete their journey, so it is unlikely they will be stopped from running for a 14-hour period.

Comment: @ArthursPass the Sunday curfew is just a training exercise, they'll resume on Monday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, if public trains and buses (or planes ?) are not operating, your options are limited.

I you are not part of an essential service, the only valid answer is **stay home**.

Respect the curfew. If you don't you might get arrested or fined and told to go back home.

If you are part of the essential services, **you should ask the relevant authorities** how would it be possible to travel on that day, and if you can do your travel on Saturday instead (for example if you absolutely need to be somewhere on Sunday).

For example, if you are a medical doctor and need to go somewhere, there might be private buses/shuttles to move essential personel around the country, and will probably be controlled to make certain no one with signs of the virus gets on board.